# Google Play Upload from Unity not Updating

Tags: unity-game-engine, upload, google-play-services

I have uploaded a new version of my app to Google Play from Unity and everything seems to be working and the new version has been published. However when i download this new version of my app the update is not included even though it displays a new version code in the google play store as well as an update button.

Have tried to uninstall and reupload a new apk again but it still sticks to the previous app version.

Any ideas why?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your AppData is wiped out before uninstalling. Have you tried downloading the new version on another device to test?